# Xcode refuses to clear cache

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, caching

I refered to this link [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4) because my Xcode Cache appears to not be clearing.

I am trying Hybrid Development with Phonegap, and am under the iOS.projx code provided by the command to create a new project. I followed the "Answer" for this question I referred to, but my cache isn't acting cleared. I earlier added a picture under the  tag, and it displayed. I deleted the line, and the picture refuses to come down. I know it's related to that picture because I added a picture title under the src command "Logo", and that still shows.

I can't see any current development on the application as of now. It won't refresh. I reset the simulators as well. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I had overlooked something when constructing the project. Under the project root file (aka, "test") there is the standard www folders and such. My Xcode Project was referring to the index.html two or three more layers down in the folder, however, right in the front directory under the "www" folder's index.html is the one I was adjusting.

The Cache is perfectly fine. Be sure that your moving the index.html and other adjustments to the proper location!